# How to intercept the click action of WebView?

Tags: android

My app has a WebView to load HTML web page, I want to implement a feature that user can click any link inside the web, then I could know which link was clicked, **but the web page couldn't jump out and still keep the unclicked state**.  I tried the below way, but it doesn't work, the WebView still would jump to the url I clicked.

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading() - url = " + url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method for this

Comment: Yes, I used it, although I asked the method to reture True, the WebView still jump to the URL also.

Comment: You may need to override `public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)` method as well

Comment: See here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html?hl=es#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)

Comment: Thank you, and I found the reason, it is my code's logic problem and nothing to do with shouldOverrideUrlLoading method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setOnTouchListener, Using this you can get clicked url

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView) v).getHitTestResult();
            Log.d(TAG, "clicked - url = " + hr.getExtra());

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, and I tried your code but I don't know why hr.getExtra() always retures null.

Comment: No, hr.getExtra() is not always return null...but you click anything nd behind it any url is there then it returns that url(for eg. "http://www.yoururl.com.....login.php"  or anything else)